# ModelAndView Spring

Tags: spring, modelandview

Details:

I am testing my first spring project , I am unable to get form data in backing bean . Here my code please help me execute this.

Welcome.jsp is my landing page from here I want to take userid and password and show in userInfo page.

Controller :--

```
package com.accounts.common.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.accounts.common.backingBean.LoginBackingBean;
/**
 * Handles requests for the application welcome page.
 */
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    /**
     * Simply selects the welcome view to render by returning void and relying
     * on the default request-to-view-translator.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value= "/welcome" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    **public ModelAndView welcome() {

        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "userForm", new LoginBackingBean());

    }**

    @RequestMapping(value="/userInfo" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userInfo(@ModelAttribute("userForm")LoginBackingBean login ,
            ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("userId" , login.getUserId());
        model.addAttribute("password" , login.getPassword());
        return "userInfo";
    }
}
```

Here is code for Welcome JSP :-- Only snapshot I am adding

```
<body>
<form id=login method="POST" action="/AccountingSW/userInfo" >
<div align="center">
<table>
<tr>
<td>User ID  : </td>
<td> <input type="text"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password :</td>
<td><input type="password"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" value ="Login"> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<label style="font-size: 10;color: red">Already existing Member</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">OR</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" value ="SignUp"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<label style="font-size: 10;color: red">New Member</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form >
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code for  UserInfo JSP :

I am putting only snapshot of what the jsp contains

```
<title>Hello ${userForm.userId}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>User Info</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>UserId</td>
        <td>${userForm.userId}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>${userForm.password}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code for  Backing Bean :--

```
package com.accounts.common.backingBean;
public class LoginBackingBean {
    private String userId;
    private String password;

    /*      Getter and setters generated */

}
```

I am able to execute the jsp(s) but the userId and Password is not getting set

Comment: it seems that you messed double quote <form id=login

Comment: didn't work even after I have put ""

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change from

```
public String userInfo(@ModelAttribute("userForm")LoginBackingBean login
```

to

```
public String userInfo(@ModelAttribute("loginBackingBean")LoginBackingBean login
```

as @ModelAttribute's document

> The default model attribute name is inferred from the declared
>   attribute type (i.e. the method parameter type or method return type),
>   based on the non-qualified class name: e.g. "orderAddress" for class
>   "mypackage.OrderAddress", or "orderAddressList" for
>   "List".

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html#name--

Comment: @RequestMapping(value= "/welcome" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {

        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "userForm", new LoginBackingBean());

    }

Answer (score 0):

In your welcome.jsp you are missing property name on inputs:

```
<td> <input type="text" name ="userId"> </td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"> </td>
```

Comment: property ? Can you please give one example

Comment: i gave you example in my answer : in your welcome.jsp you have :
    <input type="text">, but you should have : <input type="text" name ="userId">  and  for password you should have name="password"